# Python: time.mktime returning the same value for different dates

Tags: python, datetime, time, mktime

I was working on some python scripts to calculate the time spent since an older date, and surprisingly got a negative result. I realized that the problem may be in the *time.mktime* function. Let's get this code:

```
import time
import datetime

before = datetime.datetime(2010, 10, 17, 0, 0, 0)
after = datetime.datetime(2010, 10, 17, 1, 0, 0)

print "%s = %f" % (before, time.mktime(before.timetuple()))
print "%s = %f" % (after, time.mktime(after.timetuple()))
```

On my Linux 32-bit Python 2.6.4, the output is:

> 2010-10-17 00:00:00 = 1287284400.000000 
>  
>   2010-10-17 01:00:00 = 1287284400.000000

The same timestamp for different times!
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I get different ones on Python 2.6.5:

2010-10-17 00:00:00 = 1287273600.000000 ~ 
2010-10-17 01:00:00 = 1287277200.000000

Comment: @mark What is your system? I tried Linux 32 Python 2.6.5, and still got 1287284400.000000 for both dates.

Comment: I think Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams's answer is your solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. DST in Brazil [started on October 17, 2010](http://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/brazil-dst-start-2010.html), so one hour is missing.

Answer (score 1):

Note that mktime gives you the representation of your local time, with Daylight Savings if applicable to your system locale. This can lead to some odd behaviors.

You may prefer [calendar.timegm](http://docs.python.org/library/calendar.html#calendar.timegm) which gives you UTC time.